# thrift client call server, client can receive result successfully, but serve got exception

Tags: java, thrift

thrift client call server, client can receive result successfully, but serve got exception

**server**

```
TServerSocket serverTransport = new TServerSocket(9090);
TBinaryProtocol.Factory proFactory = new TBinaryProtocol.Factory();

TMultiplexedProcessor processor = new TMultiplexedProcessor();
processor.registerProcessor(
    RPCService.class.getSimpleName(), 
    new RPCService.Processor<RPCService.Iface>(new RPCServiceImpl())
);
processor.registerProcessor(
    RPCService2.class.getSimpleName(), 
    new RPCService2.Processor<RPCService2.Iface>(new RPCService2Impl())
);

TThreadPoolServer.Args serverArgs = new TThreadPoolServer.Args(serverTransport);
serverArgs.processor(processor);
serverArgs.protocolFactory(proFactory);
TServer server = new TThreadPoolServer(serverArgs);
System.out.println("Start server on port 9090...");

server.serve();
```

**client**

```
public static void startClient() {
    TTransport transport;
    try {
        transport = new TSocket("localhost", 9090);
        TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
        TMultiplexedProtocol mp1 = new TMultiplexedProtocol(protocol, RPCService.class.getSimpleName());
        TMultiplexedProtocol mp2 = new TMultiplexedProtocol(protocol, RPCService2.class.getSimpleName());
        RPCService.Client client1 = new RPCService.Client(mp1);
        RPCService2.Client client2 = new RPCService2.Client(mp2);
        transport.open();
        boolean loginResult = client1.login("aa","111");
        boolean loginResult2 = client2.login2("bb","222");
        System.out.println(loginResult+""+loginResult2);
        transport.close();
    }
```

Error:

```
14:22:30.914 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer 
- Thrift error occurred during processing of message.
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: null
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:425)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:321)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:225)
    at org.apache.thrift.TMultiplexedProcessor.process(TMultiplexedProcessor.java:101)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```